# Session in Iframe working in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, session, iframe

Im trying to get a form working in Internet Explorer. I see that when i submit this form in Firefox I can start a session and send my webbrowser to the right page based on that Session. In Internet Explorer however when i'm debugging the $_SESSION i retrieve an empty array back, this means that in Internet Explorer the session isn't started on my second page.

This is the code i'm using to print the session on my second page:

```
session_start();
 //unset($_SESSION['bp_email']);
 include("includes/_dbconnect.php");
 print_r($_SESSION);
 die();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please read this **[link](http://genotrance.wordpress.com/2006/11/23/session-cookies-rejected-by-internet-explorer/)**, it will definitely help you.

Comment: It did help me if i hadn't found the solution 3 mins before you posted your answer :). Therefore i will accept your answer. Thanks for helping!

Comment: i have the same issu.but i am using asp.net