# IFrame not working with IE

Tags: iframe

I am using iFrame to load a url in a popup within a page.I want log in to the website and perform some operations.

All this happens in the same page within an iFrame in a modal.
Except IE all browsers work fine.But in IE after one or two steps the the website is directed to the home page.
I am not able to find why this is happening.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IE is know to be different, but I wont get into that old debate here.

Since you are logging in from an iFrame, there may be something regarding session variables which is making it fail.

[Session in Iframe working in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463248/session-in-iframe-working-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer)

Other than that, I suggest debugging using debug bar to see what type of XHR requests are being made, and then determine the exact point of failure.

Comment: Did you get debug bar and check the http requests being made? If you look into these the answer might be quote obvious :) http://www.debugbar.com/download.php